# How can I execute a command from my Telegram bot from my Python code?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, chat

For example, the say hello command, I want that command to be sent from the code and the bot to return the respective response. I don't know why it only works when I enter the command via keyboard in the Telegram chat.

Here is my basic bot code:

```
BOT_TOKEN = "my token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['saludar'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hola como han estado?")

# Nueva función para manejar solicitudes programáticas
def responder_a_solicitud_programatica():
    return "Hola desde el script de Python"`

# Manejar solicitudes programáticas
`@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_programmatic_requests(message):
    if message.text.startswith('/programatica'):
        respuesta = responder_a_solicitud_programatica()
        bot.reply_to(message, respuesta)`

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,"¡Hola! Soy tu bot de Telegram")`
```

And here is my other code that sends the command to the bot but it sends it as if it were a message, I want it to do it as if it were the same user in order to get the response I want

```
import requests
import telebot


BOT_TOKEN = "my token"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)`

# Token de tu bot de Telegram
# ID de chat o nombre de usuario del destinatario
chat_id = "my chat id"

# Comando que deseas invocar
command ="/saludar"

# URL de la API de Telegram para enviar el comando al bot
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage"

# Parámetros de la solicitud POST
params = {
    "chat_id": chat_id,
    "text": command
}

# Envía la solicitud POST para invocar el comando
response = requests.post(url, params=params)

# Verifica si la solicitud fue exitosa y procesa la respuesta
if response.status_code == 200:
    respuesta_del_bot = response.json()["result"]["text"]
    print("Respuesta del bot:", respuesta_del_bot)
else:
    print(f"Error al enviar el comando: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

At the moment I have tried that but it only sends it as if it were a message when I want it to be sent as if it were a command entered by the keyboard and get the response from the bot